# Trying to float right element and aling with top element

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, display

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

But maintaining a specific div structure/hierarchy/order:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <p>LEGEND</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i>BUTTON</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried with position relative float right and display inline, but to no success.

Here are the attempts:
https://jsfiddle.net/xzmf8753/

Comment: float:left for the left one and float:right for the right one

Comment: ^ and overflow:auto to the container

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background-color: red; position: relative">
  <div style="position: relative; display: inline;">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <p style="display: inline;">LEGEND</p>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;">
    <i>BUTTON</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that does the trick!

Comment: @TemaniAfif that solution does not seem to work for this case

Comment: @RASMiranda it does if you apply the properties correctly